# how to create an extra column in DataFrame based on a simple condition in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe and I'd like to add an extra column to it based on a simple condition which basically says whether the value sof another column is equal to a given string or not. I know I can create an UDF and register it and use it then, however I think there must be an easier way of doing it. This is the psuedocode of what I'm about to do

```
df.withColumn("extra", if (col("a) == "str" 1 else 2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty much there:

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,2), (3,3), (4,5)).toDF("a", "b")
scala> df.show
+-+-+
|a|b|
+-+-+
|1|2|
|3|3|
|4|5|
+-+-+

scala> df.withColumn("New", when($"a" === $"b", "equal").otherwise("not")).show
+-+-+-----+
|a|b|  New|
+-+-+-----+
|1|2|  not|
|3|3|equal|
|4|5|  not|
+-+-+-----+
```

Note that you will need `functions` and `implicits` imported for the above to work.